# Trying to understand how to submit a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an "Activity Report" application on a first year internship, where employees can select a specific project and assign how many hours they have worked on it per day.

The selection of projects (depending on the employees id) and the display of the page seem to be working. But here's my problem : once I click on the displayed image that is supposed to submit the form - it seems to reload the page as if nothing happened !

The View line of the submission is as following :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActivityInputCreate", "Project"))
       { %>
[...]

<td>
    <input type="image" style="border: 0; width: 16px;" src="../../Content/Black_16x16/Save.png" onclick="this.form.submit" alt="save" />
    <input type="image" style="border: 0; width: 16px;" src="../../Content/Black_16x16/Cancel.png" onclick="    window.location.href = '/Project/ActivityInputIndex'; return false;" alt="cancel" /></td>
         <!-- the first line being to save and the second to cancel -->
<td>
}
```

I don't know how to handle a form submission but here's the controller (the first of the same name being the non [HttpPost] one :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActivityInputCreate(Project objToCreate, FormCollection form)
        {
            string year = form["Years"];
            int iyear = int.Parse(year);
            string month = form["Months"];
            int imonth = int.Parse(month);
            string strUser = Environment.UserName.ToLower();

            CalendarController c = new CalendarController();
            ViewBag.ListYears = c.ListYears(iyear);
            ViewBag.ListMonths = c.ListMonths(imonth);
            ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth = _service.ListDaysOfMonth(iyear.ToString(), imonth.ToString());

            //nea11
            Session["ActivityInputYear"] = iyear.ToString();
            Session["ActivityInputMonth"] = imonth.ToString();

            ProjectResourceManagerService pr = new ProjectResourceManagerService(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));
            ViewBag.ProjectList = pr.ListProject();

            List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> ddlists = new List<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>();

            foreach (string s in ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth)
                ddlists.Add(_service.ListHours(0)); //id de UserActivity à la place de 0

            ViewBag.ddlists = ddlists;

            //nea12
            string strProject = form["Project"];

            //nea13
            string strSep = ";";
            string strDatas = "";
            int l = 0;
            foreach (var jour in ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth)
            {
                string nom = "Hours" + l.ToString();
                strDatas += form[nom] + strSep;
                l++;
            }

            //ajout dans la base
            UserActivityDb db = new UserActivityDb(@"metadata=res://*/Models.CRA.csdl|res://*/Models.CRA.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRA.msl;provider=Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL server;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CRAV34;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=as0;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;");
            if (null != strProject)
                db.setFormattedData(iyear, imonth, ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth, int.Parse(strProject), strUser, strDatas, true);

            IEnumerable<Project> lp = _service.List(strUser, iyear.ToString(), imonth.ToString());
            lp = lp.Where(p => (true == db.ExistUserActivity(iyear, imonth, ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth, p.ProjectId, strUser)));


            //nea35
            List<string[]> lstInts = new List<string[]>();

            foreach (Project p in lp)
            {
                string strInts = db.getFormattedData(iyear, imonth, ViewBag.ListDaysOfMonth, p.ProjectId, strUser, null, 0);
                string[] ints = strInts.Split(';');

                lstInts.Add(ints);

            }
            ViewBag.ProjectInts = lstInts;

            return View("ActivityInputIndex", lp);
        }
```

I'd love to give you more precision but please keep in mind that most of the code isn't mine and is the last interns'.

TL;DR : Display of the page is fine, I want to submit once the DropDownList are filled, submission button doesn't do anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the `onclick="this.form.submit"` from the first one. A `<input type="image" >` is a submit button (and in any case it would need to be `.submit()`)

Comment: I removed it and it didn't seem to change anything, must I add another way of submitting or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Just try initially with `<input type="submit" value="save" />` (comment out the other 2) If that's not working, then there are other issues with your code

Comment: I tried that in the beginning of my research, sadly it doesn't seem to work.  What should I take into consideration when it comes to submitting a form? From where could the issue come from? EDIT : Or to be more precise, once I click on the button, what does the program do?

Comment: Is your controller method being hit. Do you have `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in your view? There could be any number of reasons

Comment: @Html.AntiForgeryToken() -> No, additionally, the bulletpoint I've put in the HttpPost controller shows me I reach it once I press the button to submit.

Comment: Its a break point :). But that means your form is submitting so what is you real problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89002/discussion-between-aruixe-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue came with the input of my username (through the SQL INSERT).

```
  string strUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

Is used with :

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = sLogin;
```

And works just fine. The issue was not with the sending of a form (which it did receive) but the way the SQL request was built.